How do i automatically resize the table TR or TD when the elements inside is displayed or hidden?
I have a Form with Mat-Form controls. Below is the code
<table style="height: 100%">
  <tr >
    <td>
      First Name
    </td>
    <td>
      <mat-form-field
        appearance="outline"
        subscriptSizing="dynamic"
      >
        <input matInput [formControlName]="control.name" />
        <mat-error
          *ngIf="this.myForm.get(control.name)?.hasError('required')"
        >
          {{ control.label }} is required
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

When there is a required field error, the error text appears, however the text overlaps with the next control. I want the Row of a table to automatically grow based on the error. Something like in the screen shot


I do not recommend your approach because it causes layout shift. Consider always allocating error message area.

sorry, i didnt get, i thought this is the default behaviour of Material Form components

mat-form-field has bottom space to show error or hint in default. Are you customizing it?

I want to expand that space when error occurs, else collapse the space
